# doctrine OneToMany - cascade persist not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this issue where doctrine won't save `ArrayCollection` on persist(). I have `Post` and I am adding `Tag` to it from form submit and then trying to save it (basic stuff). On persist() the `Post` is saved, but tags relations are not.

Dumping the `Post` before persist() shows that tags are there.
[image]

What am I missing?

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TagRepository")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="tags", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TagType", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", mappedBy="tag")
     */
    private $posts;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPost(): ?Post
    {
        return $this->post;
    }

    public function setPost(?Post $post): self
    {
        $this->post = $post;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?TagType
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?TagType $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Post[]
     */
    public function getPosts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    public function addPost(Post $post): self
    {
        if (!$this->posts->contains($post)) {
            $this->posts[] = $post;
            $post->addTag($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePost(Post $post): self
    {
        if ($this->posts->contains($post)) {
            $this->posts->removeElement($post);
            $post->removeTag($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function formChoice()
    {
        return "<span style='color: {$this->getType()->getColor()};'>{$this->name}</span>";
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $file_orig;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="posts")
     */
    private $tag;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ImageSize", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $imageSize;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->tag = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    public function setSize(int $size): self
    {
        $this->size = $size;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Tag[]
     */
    public function getTags(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags[] = $tag;
            $tag->setPost($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag): self
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($tag->getPost() === $this) {
                $tag->setPost(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFile(): ?string
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(string $file): self
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFileOrig(): ?string
    {
        return $this->file_orig;
    }

    public function setFileOrig(string $file_orig): self
    {
        $this->file_orig = $file_orig;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Tag[]
     */
    public function getTag(): Collection
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function getImageSize(): ?ImageSize
    {
        return $this->imageSize;
    }

    public function setImageSize(?ImageSize $imageSize): self
    {
        $this->imageSize = $imageSize;

        // set (or unset) the owning side of the relation if necessary
        $newPost = null === $imageSize ? null : $this;
        if ($imageSize->getPost() !== $newPost) {
            $imageSize->setPost($newPost);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb. I was adding Tags to the `tags` property in the entity, instead of to the `tag` property.

Comment: As it is only a simple typo it is better to delete the entire post as recommended by SO